# Visual Studio Code save language mode (override default)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have some ASP files in a folder. I would like to view some of them using the default ASP language mode, others I prefer to view in HTML.

If I switch a file to use HTML, it doesn't remember that setting next time I open VS Code.

Is it possible to save this setting per file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`"files.associations"`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_common-questions) setting. You can specify this setting for each file or also for complete directories:

```json
"files.associations": {
    "**/somefolder/*.asp": "html", // add complete folder
    "**/myfileName.asp": "html" // add a specific file 
}
```