# Is there a way to set default file type as "all files" for vscode on windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running vscode on windows 10.

```
Version: 1.40.2 (system setup)
Commit: f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520
Date: 2019-11-25T14:54:45.096Z
Electron: 6.1.5
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17134
```

each time I save a new file, vscode consider it as a plain text by default.

[image]

this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48456682/12492163) gives an approach to set the defalut language.

## question

is there a way to set default file type as "all files"?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Not an answer (yet)**

I have the same issue where an "unknown" file extension causes the VSCode `Save as`  file chooser dialog on Windows defaults to `Plain Text(*.txt;*.gitignore)`, regardless of Language Mode (e.g. Plain Text, also HTML) and then always appends ".txt" to the filename, requiring fiddling with the dropdown to set the file type to `All Files (*.*)`.

While it seems possible to set the default language and setup custom file type associations (e.g. [Visual Studio Code save language mode (override default)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319090/visual-studio-code-save-language-mode-override-default),  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_common-questions) I have not been successful in affecting the Save As Dialog in any way (even with manually setting the language).

A quick glance at 
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/workbench/services/dialogs/browser/abstractFileDialogService.ts#L281 (which may be the completely wrong place) caused me to try

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.ext": "*"
}
```

and

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.ext": ""
}
```

but that did not change anything for me (except breaking the syntax highlighting of at least the `settings.json`).

Feel free to update this with further information..